# how to add a user on 100 servers when there is no NIS

Tags: linux

How  to add a single users in all the 100 servers When there is no centralization for adding users.
What would be the best way to add users in all the 100 systems

Comment: Fix "there is no centralization for adding users" first.

Comment: Is implementing LDAP or NIS or some other centralized authentication scheme not an option?

Comment: a user should be able to login in from all the systems no centralization for adding users

Comment: Well, if you can't add centralized authentication (LDPA, NIS, w/e), or centralized configuration management (ansible, puppet, chef, w/e), then in order to add a user on 100 servers... you'll have to add a user on 100 servers.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not meant to be a full answer)

I've been working with Ansible lately.  Love it or hate it, this is a perfect fit for exactly what you're attempting to ask.

With that assumption, these steps will work pretty darn quick.

From: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html

```
$ git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
$ cd ./ansible
$ source ./hacking/env-setup
```

From: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_adhoc.html

Create an inventory file of your hosts

```
$ ansible all -m user -a "name=foo password=<crypted password here>"
```